# lodash/underscore find objects by key that is in values of array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have this array of objects:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'test 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'test 2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'test 3'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'test 4'
    }
]
```

I have this array of IDs:

```
[1, 3]
```

How can I select all objects whose `id` property exists in the IDs array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ids = [1, 3];
var found = _.where(items, function (item) {
    return ids.indexOf(item.id) !== -1;
});
```